# testing svelte lib with jest fails

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, svelte

I am playing around with sveltekit, and I have a "pure" js file that defines a quadTree and some functions for manipulating it.

All works fine, but it is growing to a size where it would really help to have some unit tests.
So I installed jest, and it just fails.

if I write

```
import quadTree from './quadTree';
```

I get the error

```
cannot use import statement outside a module
```

all solutions I find when searching for this error seems to be react focused and unless I misunderstand something, they all suggest dragging in react dependencies which I of course do not want.

and if I change to

```
const quadTree = require('./quadTree');
```

I instead get the error

```
unexpected token 'export'
```

so question is: how do I get around this issue, and maybe jest is not the best fit here, in which case: what would be better?

Comment: any news/clue on this issue? I'm facing the very same problem, trying to set up tests for my SvelteKit project...

Comment: way too long since I worked on it so I don't remember the solution... but looks like the repo builds. You might be able to reverse engineer a solution from it https://github.com/munHunger/dnd/blob/master/dmScreen/src/lib/quadTree.spec.js

Comment: Thanks. I found a very nice library that I highly recommend those who wants to configure tests on a SvelteKit project : https://github.com/rossyman/svelte-add-jest